# What html elements can addEventListener not be attached to?

Tags: javascript, html

I have been researching how to write a simple function that attaches a listener to a passed in HTML element.

I have been having some confusion with this if statement:

```
if (elem.addEventListener){
//etc
}
```

I assume elem.addEventListener returns true if the element has the ability to add a listener? Is this correct?  If so, in what cases will this return false?

Comment: Older browsers, that don't support `addEventListener` (but perhaps `attachEvent` instead).

Comment: Oh okay, so its just a check to see if the browser will support it?

Comment: gotcha this explains the `else if{ (elem.attachEvent) }`

Comment: You could also write if ('addEventListener' in elem) { //etc } for the same purpose

Comment: Yup. Personally I would only have that *once* in my code: inside a custom-made `addEvent` function that I have programmed to accept either an element or array of elements, an event or array of events, and a handler or array of handlers. Cross-browser and multi-purpose!

Comment: @user2210274 If you don't need to support IE8, you don't need check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Internet Explorer doesn't support `addEventListener` until version 9.  This is simply a check to ensure the browser supports it.